# C++ equivalent of java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, c++, limits

How can I get an equivalent of java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE on C++?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#include <limits>    
std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you mean by "equivalent". `java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE` is a compile-time constant in Java, but `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` is not an integer constant expression in C++. So it can't be used for example as an array size (well, the min value of an int can't anyway because it's negative, but the same goes for expressions involving it, or other similar values, or other contexts requiring an i.c.e).

If you need a compile-time constant in C++, use `INT_MIN` from `<climits>`. In fact you may as well use it anyway: `numeric_limits` is essential if you're writing generic code, and you have some integer type T which might be `int`, or might be something else. Its primary use otherwise is to prove your leet C++ skillz, and/or make your code longer ;-)

Comment: Though in C++0x it's a constant-expression. :)

Comment: I'll believe in C++0x when I put my back out lifting it ;-)